# Find temporal distance based on value of variable in panel data

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

Let's define these two variables, for year and level of conflict in that year

```
set.seed(28100)

years <- 1900:2010
conflict_lev <- sample(0:4, 111, replace = T, prob = c(0.9, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01))

my_df <- data.frame(years, conflict_lev)
```

Now, for each `year` I want to calculate the number of years since the last time `conflict_lev` was more than 0. This can be found with this loop:

```
my_df$dist_last_conflict <- NA

for (i in 1:length(years)) {
  my_df$dist_last_conflict[i] <- min(years[i] - years[years < years[i] & conflict_lev > 0])
}
```

Nevertheless, I am struggling to create `dist_last_conflict` with `dplyr` and when I have multiple groups as defined in the variable `group`.

Ideally, I should be able to define a function `findDistLastConflict()` that get the same result as above and without loop:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>% 
group_by(group) %>% 
mutate(dist_last_conflict = findDistLastConflict(conflict_lev, years))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to alternative approaches, you can create an indicator for each period of peace, then use `seq(1, n())` with each period:

```
my_df %>%
  mutate(peaceful.period = cumsum(conflict_lev!=0)) %>%
  group_by(peaceful.period) %>%
  mutate(dist_last_conflict = seq(1, n())-1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-peaceful.period)

# A tibble: 111 x 3
   years conflict_lev dist_last_conflict
   <int>        <int>              <dbl>
 1  1900            0                  0
 2  1901            0                  1
 3  1902            0                  2
 4  1903            0                  3
 5  1904            0                  4
 6  1905            0                  5
 7  1906            0                  6
 8  1907            0                  7
 9  1908            0                  8
10  1909            0                  9
# ... with 101 more rows
```